# Why is the regular expression not matching the string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a text file that contains strings that look like:

```
IX: {Series|(}                  {9}
IX: {Series!geometric!infinite} {13}
IX: {Series!geometric|(}        {13}
IX: {Series!geometric!finite|(} {13}
```

I only want the parts that are within the curly braces. In order to do this, I made a regular expression and added the strings to a list.

```
public static LinkedList readFile(File file) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
        Matcher matcher;
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            while(matcher.find()){
                list.add(matcher.group(1));
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return list;
}
```

This returns, using the first string as an example, "Series|(" and "9". Now, I would like to remove the last two characters out of any string that contains the "|(" or ")|" in it. So for example, I would like to have "Series" instead of "Series|(". I tried modifying my reg expression to be

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)^[|\\(\\)]\\}");
```

but this returned no matches whatsoever. My thought process was that I want everything within the curly braces except any part that contains the characters "|", "(" or ")". Could someone explain what is wrong with my expression?

Comment: `[^` instead of `^[`

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to return strings that look like "Series|(}    {"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)([|(]{2})?\\}");
```

Breaking down "([|(]{2})?", it is saying one of the characters "|", "(" twice, and then making this optional. So, "|(", "(|" or "" (nothing) would actually match.

Comment: `"||"` and `"(("` would also match.  This may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex should look like this:

```
\{([^\}\|]*)(\|\()?\}
```

Explanation:

- first, `\{` matches the { at the start
- then, `([^\}\|]*)` matches anything between the {}, but not the |( at the end
- the next step, `(\|\()?`, matches the |( at the end if present, else it doesn't match anything
- at the end, `\}` matches the } at the end

**[Here is a running demo of the regex](http://regex101.com/r/yW0vA9/1)**

Comment: Thanks! Will the pattern also work for strings containing "|)"? The strings in the file contain either "|(", "|)", or neither. Thank you for the explanation by the way.

Comment: @JeremyFisher Currently it won't allow that, but you can change it easy so that it does: http://regex101.com/r/aL3uN9/2